# AS2 Enemy 'sliding' off of each other

Tags: flash, actionscript, collision-detection, collision

What would be the best way to handle enemies 'sliding' off of each other and preventing them from overlapping? This is often used in 3D games. I'm not really sure where to start, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

First, it may make sense to use an existing library such as Box2D.

Secondly, the sliding problem is usually caused by your hit testing code. More than likely, you wait for two enemies to hit each other, detect with hitTest, and then you move them back a little bit. The sliding probably happens from repeatedly hitting, moving back, moving forward, hitting, moving back, moving forward, hitting, moving back...

Basic solution to your problem is to detect that the enemies are going to hit in the next iteration, and avoid the actual hit. You need to work out where the enemies are going to be in the next iteration, and then check if, in the next iteration, their bounding boxes are going to intersect. If they are going to intersect on the next iteration, you need to handle a 'hit'.

So basically, your enemies never hit or overlap. You always prevent it.